# Getting potentially large amounts of data from a website: Should I use Scrapy or urllib2?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm not new to programming—but am (very) new to web-scraping. I'd like to get data from [this](http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=179&teamid=4411&eventid=0&gameid=2) website in this manner:

1. Get the team-data from the given URL and store it in some text file.
2. "Click" the links of each of the team members and store *that* data in some other text file.
3. Click various other specific links and store data in its own separate text file.

Again, I'm quite new to this. I have tried opening the specified website with *urllib2* (in hopes of being able to parse it with BeautifulSoup), but opening it resulted in a timeout.

Ultimately, I'd like to do something like specify a team's URL to a script, and have said script update associated text files of the team, its players, and various other things in different links.

Considering what I want to do, would it be better to learn how to create a web-crawler, or directly do things via urllib2? I'm under the impression that a spider is faster, but will basically click on links at random unless told to do otherwise (I do not know whether or not this impression is accurate).

Comment: I recommend starting out with the native/raw approach, i.e. with urllib(2) or requests (Google for "Python requests library"), and BeautifulSoup. You'll have fun learning the concepts, and it is not a huge amount of work. Especially, by using this approach you learn a lot about the data that you want to obtain. Sooner or later you will hit some limitations (what do you mean with "large amounts" by the way? this is quite a relative term), and you will need to manage them. In any case, the experiences you will obtain by tackling this with urllib/BS will help, so just go for it!

Comment: here's [code example of what @Jan-Philip Gehrcke said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14338006/4279)