# Python Subprocess for Notepad

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, notepad

I am trying to open Notepad using popen and write something into it. I can't get my head around it. I can open Notepad using command:

notepadprocess=subprocess.Popen('notepad.exe')

I am trying to identify how can I write anything in the text file using python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you write to a file directely?

Comment: I am trying to Automate it :)

Comment: You don't have to open notepad. You can write to a file from python.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/ (UIAutomation)

Comment: related: [Interact with other programs using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279)

Comment: Thanks Alex and J.F. I am looking at both the options now.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. pywinauto does the exact thing I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can at first write something into txt file (ex. foo.txt) and then open it with notepad:

```
import os

f = open('foo.txt','w')
f.write('Hello world!')
f.close()
os.system("notepad.exe foo.txt")
```

Comment: I can do this, but I am trying to open a notepad with some text (using python) in it.

Comment: @BashNoob: what happens if you run Tim Osadchiy's code? I expect that it opens notepad with `Hello world!` text in it. What do you see?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I can do this, but I found more efficient way by using pywinauto.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing the concept of (text) file with the processes that manipulate them.

Notepad is a **program**, of which you can create a **process**. A **file**, on the other hand, is just a structure on your hard drive.

From a programming standpoint, **Notepad doesn't edit files**. It:

- reads a file into computer memory
- modifies the content of that memory
- writes that memory back into a file (which could be similarly named, or otherwise - which is known as the "Save as" operation).

Your *program*, just as any other program, can manipulate files, just as notepad does. In particular, you can perform exactly the same sequence as Notepad:

```
my_file= "myfile.txt"        #the name/path of the file
with open(file, "rb") as f:  #open the file for reading
    content= f.read()        #read the file into memory
content+= "mytext"           #change the memory
with open(file, "wb") as f:  #open the file for writing
    f.write( content )       #write the memory into the file
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am trying to to the third part. So This is what I am trying to do - open notepad and write something into it, just like opening cmd prompt and sending commands using popen.communicate..

Answer (score 0):

Found the exact solution from Alex K's comment. I used pywinauto to perform this task.

Comment: Consider what is said in [@Matteo Italia's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14338006/4279). It may also apply in your case.